# Magento2- How to copy custom data from quote to order and order item

Tags: magento2

I am building a custom module in Magento 2 that has a custom discount. I am trying to copy the discount from quote, quote item to order and order item.
In Magento 1, I declare the config.xml like this:

```xml
    <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote_address>
                <custom_discount_amount><to_order>*</to_order></custome_discount_amount>
                <base_custom_discount_amount><to_order>*</to_order></base_custome_discount_amount>
            </sales_convert_quote_address>
            <sales_convert_quote_item>
                <custome_discount_amount><to_order_item>*</to_order_item></custome_discount_amount>
                <base_custom_discount_amount><to_order_item>*</to_order_item></base_custom_discount_amount>
            </sales_convert_quote_item>
        </fieldsets>
```

and my custom discount amount was copied to tables: `sales_flat_order` and `sales_flat_order_item` as expected.

In Magento 2, I created a file named `fieldset.xml` with this code:

```xml
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Object/etc/fieldset.xsd">
    <scope id="global">
        <fieldset id="sales_convert_quote_item">
            <field name="custom_discount_amount">
                <aspect name="to_order_item" />
            </field>
            <field name="base_custom_discount_amount">
                <aspect name="to_order_item" />
            </field>
        </fieldset>         
          <fieldset id="sales_convert_quote_address">
            <field name="custom_discount_amount">
                <aspect name="to_order" />
            </field>
            <field name="base_custom_discount_amount">
                <aspect name="to_order" />
            </field>
        </fieldset>   
    </scope>
</config>
```

but there is no success.
What else do I need to do in Magento 2 to make it work? Can you guys please help me?

Comment: Did you fid out how this should be done?

Answer (score 4):

In Magento 2 without using fieldset you can also copy custom data from quote item to order item by using plugin.

create **di.xml** in your module etc folder.
**app/code/Vender/Yourmodule/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem">
        <plugin name="cedapi_quote_to_order_item" type="Vender\Yourmodule\Model\Plugin\Quote\QuoteToOrderItem"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create a class to your module and define a function. **app/code/Vender/Yourmodule/Model/Plugin/Quote**
Create **QuoteToOrderItem.php** file

```
<?php
namespace Vender\Yourmodule\Model\Plugin\Quote;

use Closure;

class QuoteToOrderItem
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem $item
     * @param array $additional
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
  public function aroundConvert(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem $subject,
        Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem $item,
        $additional = []
    ) {
        /** @var $orderItem \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item */
        $orderItem = $proceed($item, $additional);//result of function 'convert' in class 'Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem' 
        $orderItem->setCustomDesign($item->getCustomDesign());//set your required
        return $orderItem;// return an object '$orderItem' which will replace result of function 'convert' in class 'Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem'
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

After spend some time and research issue, i stucked here:
Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement.php
line 446

```
public function mergeDataObjects(
    $interfaceName,
    $firstDataObject,
    $secondDataObject
) {
    if (!$firstDataObject instanceof $interfaceName || !$secondDataObject instanceof $interfaceName) {
        throw new \LogicException('Wrong prototype object given. It can only be of "' . $interfaceName . '" type.');
    }
    $secondObjectArray = $this->objectProcessor->buildOutputDataArray($secondDataObject, $interfaceName);
    $this->_setDataValues($firstDataObject, $secondObjectArray, $interfaceName);
    return $this;
}
```

Which ignores converted attributes because logic of merging based on presence getters and setters of target model\interface. So, if you converting attributes which haven't setters and getters in target model they will be ignored here:
Magento\Framework\Reflection\DataObjectProcessor.php line 75

```
public function buildOutputDataArray($dataObject, $dataObjectType)
{
    $methods = $this->methodsMapProcessor->getMethodsMap($dataObjectType);
    $outputData = [];

    /** @var MethodReflection $method */
    foreach (array_keys($methods) as $methodName) {
        if (!$this->methodsMapProcessor->isMethodValidForDataField($dataObjectType, $methodName)) {
            continue;
        }

        $value = $dataObject->{$methodName}();
        $isMethodReturnValueRequired = $this->methodsMapProcessor->isMethodReturnValueRequired(
            $dataObjectType,
            $methodName
        );
```

Maybe you might to use observer or plugin to avoid this problem. (issue encountered in 2.0.6 Magento version)

Answer (score 1):

For anybody looking at this in the future, the fact that the fieldset XML doesn't work has been acknowledged by Magento as a bug. There is a core patch available in the ticket (not reproduced here since it may need to be tweaked with new Magento versions).

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5823